# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration$Defaults

Tags: java, json, maven, csv, jsonpath

I'm trying to use this library Json2flat, i've add in my pom this dependencies :

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.github.opendevl</groupId>
 <artifactId>json2flat</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
 <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
 <version>2.2.0</version><!--INO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
</dependency>
```

When i do `JFlat flatMe = new JFlat(json);` i got this exception :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration$Defaults
```

here is the link of the librairy in Github :

https://github.com/opendevl/Json2Flat

Comment: try to reimport all dependencies or clean install should help.

Comment: I've dot it 'maven clean install' many times

Comment: either reimport from Intellij should work, or directly go to mvn repository location manually delete all versions. try clean install after that.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your 'mvn clean install' is failed. I see the latest version available in default mvn repo is 1.0.3 while you have specified 2.2.0. Try updating the version to reflect the actuals (i.e., 1.0.3)

Comment: You mean i change the dependency of jsonpath to 1.0.3 ? If i dot this, i got a maven install failed

Comment: I have tried it with the quoted dependencies, and for me it works. If you use intellij then right click on the pom.xml and re-import it.

Comment: What do u mean by 'quoted dependencies' ? i use eclipse